# Data mask and other HTML features are not applying on input field with Django Forms

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django forms to apply some basic html feature such as data mask and input pattern. Below is the code on the forms.py for one of the input fields.

```
'contact_person' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class':'form-control capitalize','pattern':'[a-zA-Z]*'}),
```

or data mask

```
'primary_phone_no' : forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class':'form-control','data-mask':"000 000 000"}),
```

Once I make the changes and see the changes on the browser, inspect element and locate that field, I can clearly see the changes had been applied on the HTML but when I put the input I see no changes has taken place. Means nor of the feature such as datamask or pattern is happening.

Its a very strange thing I am facing. Did someone came across this and is there something am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the order of where you set the widget settings. This works:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    contact_person = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control capitalize',
        'pattern': '[a-zA-Z]*'
    }))
    primary_phone_no = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'data-mask': '000 000 000'
    }))
```